# Subdividing mesh causes certain parts of mesh to be visible through transparent textures?

Tags: mesh, transparency

I'm editing a mesh where the tips of the hair is partially transparent, and when I do anything to the mesh (tris to quads, subdivide, adding edgeloops) it causes parts of the mesh to be visible through the texture but not others. Here's what it looks like:

https://gyazo.com/54b3afd1e04d34c29a24140e62145154

I've already checked and this has nothing to do with normals, so i have no idea what's up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please share this part of your mesh? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots sure! heres a link to the mesh: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ANp1Tm4hasdujhjRMDgBEVWeT5HDA0cp/view?usp=sharing

and heres a link to the texture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15BZlH6W9E0sspRVMFRm7-jKKl-soMnO6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: oh ok it's Blender Render, I don't know enough about it

Comment: @moonboots oh okay. I didn't realize that was something I had to mention. Thanks for trying, though! Have a good day!